# Akka.net .NET Core configuration

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, akka, .net-7.0, akka.net

I'm trying to configure akka.net in an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API.

I added akka.net config into `appsettings.json` but the configuration still does not work. What am I doing wrong? How to configure akka.net 1.5.13 in .NET 7?

```json
{
    "akka": {
        "stdout-loglevel": "DEBUG",
        "stdout-logger-class": "Akka.Event.StandardOutLogger",
        "log-config-on-start": "off",
        "loglevel": "DEBUG",
        "loggers": [ "Akka.Logger.NLog.NLogLogger,Akka.Logger.NLog" ],
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
builder.Services
    .AddAkka("ActorSystem", (builder, _) =>
    {
        builder.AddHoconFile("akka.hocon", HoconAddMode.Prepend)
        .WithActors((system, registry, resolver) =>
        {
          // init your actors here 
        }
    }
```

Your akka settings should be in the `akka.hocon` file.

Better way would be using Akka.Hosting since you're using WebApi.

https://github.com/akkadotnet/Akka.Hosting

Comment: By default, there is no such method 'AddAkka' what package/reference should be added to get this method?

Comment: `AddAkka` is part of Akka.Hosting

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to configure Akka.net, maybe it's not the best way, but it works.

1. Put configuration into a separate file: `akka.config`. Here is example of the content of this file:

   ```
   akka {
       stdout-loglevel = DEBUG
       loglevel = DEBUG
       log-config-on-start = on
   }
   ```
2. When you create the Actor system, you should read and parse this config and provide it to the Actor system:

   ```cs
   var config =
   ConfigurationFactory.ParseString(
       File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "akka.config")));
   builder.Services.AddSingleton<ActorSystem>(_ => ActorSystem.Create("MySystem",config));
   ```

Useful links: [code project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1007161/A-Look-At-Akka-NET)